# Why does the SSH session not die after rm -rf /?

Tags: bash, rm

Just for fun, on a VPS I was about to terminate anyway, I ran

```
sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
```

and after that all commands, including

```
/bin/bash
```

returned command not found, which makes sense as they were deleted. But how was I still SSHed into it, and able to somewhat use bash even though the files no longer existed?

Comment: Because instance of shell is still in memory. You delete filesystem, but not what's in RAM. That's why some files are recoverable from RAM even if they're deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS and services run in memory, so they can keep running (but of course they cannot load anything from disk any more).

You will also not be able to open another ssh-session :-)